# Xamarin Activity OnBackPressed() not firing

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin android app which has two activities. The first is a login activity (`LoginActivity`) which when a successful login occurs, it calls `StartActivity`(`MainActivity`). I'm trying to prevent the MainActivity from navigating back to the `LoginActivity` when the back button is pressed and have attempted to override `OnBackPressed()` however this method never fires on `MainActivity`. I have the overridden the same method in `LoginActivity` which fires perfectly.

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    // Do nothing
    string test = ""; // Setting a breakpoint here and it's never hit.
}
```

I have also tried overriding `OnKeyDown()` which also never fires on `MainActivity`.

```
public override bool OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
{
    if (keyCode == Keycode.Home)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
}
```

The only method I can see that is firing when i press the back button on `MainActivity` is `OnPause()`.

Is there something special that i'm missing from `MainActivity` to allow me to override `OnBackPressed()`?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the `NoHistory` in the activity attribute to prevent the login activity to be navigated back to. Example:
**Login Activity:**

```
namespace Xamarin.Droid.NoHistory
{
    [Activity(Label = "LoginActivity", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", NoHistory = true)]
    public class LoginActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LoginLayout);

            Button startMainActivityButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.login_button);
            startMainActivityButton.Click += (sender, args) =>
            {
                StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
            };

        }

    }
}
```

**Main Activity**:

```
namespace Xamarin.Droid.NoHistory
{
    [Activity(Label = "MainActivity")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code of the two activities, and to help you even more, I have added this example on GitHub here: https://github.com/tiger4589/Xamarin.Droid.NoHistoryExample

Comment: Thanks Paul. Is there anything required on MainActivity for this to work? I've added the NoHistory attribute to LoginActivity however it still navigates me back to the LoginActivity when i press the back button.

Comment: @JMG I have updated my answer to show you both activities code, and I added the example I tried on GitHub, feel free to check it all.

Comment: Thanks again Paul. This works fine on my Galaxy S6 Edge however on a Lollipop (5.1) device it fails. On 5.1, pressing back closes the application in your sample app. There must be some incompatibility or bug with 5.1 perhaps.

Comment: In my application I have chosen 6.0 as the only targeted version for Android, you can change that and try it.

Comment: On a side note: do you mean pressing the back button in main activity or login activity? Because it should close and not go back to login activity from the main activity.

Comment: It turns out the application wasn't being updated on the device when making changes and then debugging. I had to reset the device for it to work (Tried cleaning the solution and manually deleting bin/ and obj/. Your solution does work now on both devices. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: onBackPressed() is now firing on both devices as well.